# How to type nested objects with a value that matches its key in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have an object of objects like:

```
const CATEGORIES = {
  diet: {
    id: 'diet',
    title: 'Diet',
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

How can I write a type for it so that TypeScript will ensure that the nested `id` property will match the object's key in the parent?

I've tried...

```
const CATEGORIES: {
  [T in string]: {
    id: T
    title: string
  }
} = { ... }
```

...but this seems to still accept any strings for `id`.

I'm assuming it uses mapped types and generics somehow, but I can't quite figure out what the syntax is, if it's even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't map over all of `string` and have it act the way you want here; see [microsoft/TypeScript#22509](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/22509).  You'll need a set of [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) keys to map over.  One way to achieve this is to use a generic helper function which infers those keys from the passed-in value, and verifies that the `id` subproperty of each property matches its key:

```
const asCategories = <T extends { [K in keyof T]: { id: K, title: string } }>(t: T) => t;
```

You can test to see that it's happy with good values:

```
const CATEGORIES = asCategories({
  diet: {
    id: 'diet',
    title: 'Diet',
    //...
  },
  //...
}); // okay
```

and angry with bad ones:

```
const BADCATEGORIES = asCategories({
  diet: { id: "diet", title: "Diet" },
  exercise: { id: "exersice", title: "Exercise" } // error!
  // -------> ~~
  // Type '"exersice"' is not assignable to type '"exercise"'.
})
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhhAwnKBTA5iATgS1RGAXhgB4AVGVADzTABMCBvGAbQGkYcwYBrVATxAAzGGQC6ALhjMcdKWwA0MKDigAbVFOi4w6GAF8DAPgAUUKWQCURI8oDcAKAehIsRAEEyAUQDiAeQAlAEkvAGUieCQUDGw8CBNGBxgYOjxzaSTkzjkYAHJU1ChchUzklXVNPIARNOLSmAB6BoA6VphM-RLkptbmh31LO0aGmBAeOH4nF2gYACF3Ko9vf2CwiIRkNExcfATMgvSZHIAiA+Olco0pY5rC44MuyipULGAcCEqj6+oXiBxgVDnZSqK4wY5eZ6vd6AgzDShYLDYACEmSaMAAtJisejbAA-XGokZkfgAB1QeWOPywfwBx1ynAIYBAsAQf3QYDgACMNMoQMpSeTcpTIW8PnS+gMgA)

Comment: Thank you @jcalz! I keep forgetting about the identity function approach when I think I've tried everything, but it's an interesting way to solve these more complex typing problems.